# Spring boot logback: ERROR in RollingFileAppender Failed to create parent directories for [/./logs/npo-api.log]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-logback

I have a `Spring-Boot` application with this `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs" />

    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>
                %date %green(%level{5}) %yellow([%thread]) %cyan(%logger{10}) [%file : %line] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/npo-api.log</file>
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOGS}/npo-api-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.npo" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

I copied jar file to `/var/npoapi/` directory. I also created a `logs` directory under this path: `/var/npiapi/logs`.

I chnaged the owner of these directories to `npoapi` user and run the service with the same user:

```
[Unit]
Description=npoapi
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=npoapi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar /var/npoapi/api-0.0.1.jar
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - Failed to create parent directories for [/./logs/npo-api.log]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[RollingFile] - openFile(./logs/npo-api.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/npo-api>
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:179)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
```